# How to join two dictionaries with overlapping key values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example if my dictionaries are,

```
dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d',2:'e'}
```

Then I want the joined dictionary to be,

```
{1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d',5:'e'}
```

Comment: is, a,b,c.. a string type ? or an object?

Comment: `key` of new `dict` start from `1` to `total elemetns in two dict` ??

Comment: do you want to combine two dict?

Comment: @user1767754 sorry about that. Edited the question

Comment: @magsheer what if you combined `{1:'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}` and `{10: 'a', 11: 'b'}`?

Comment: @AdamSmith In that case I would just do an update but all my dictionaries have ordered keys starting from 1

Comment: @magsheer I'm confused though. It seems like your data structure is wrong. Maybe you shouldn't be using a dict at all?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't care about the keys at all. So just figure out what order you want to join the dictionaries in and do:

```
import itertools

ordered_dicts = [dict1, dict2]  # N.B. normal dicts, not OrderedDicts!
ordered_values = [v for d in itertools.chain(ordered_dicts) for _, v in sorted(d.items())]
result = dict(zip(itertools.count(1), ordered_values))
```

Comment: itertools.count is kind of overpowered here -- wouldn't `enumerate` work too?  My first thought was something like `dict(enumerate((v for d in dd for k,v in sorted(d.items())), 1))`.

Comment: I got a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` for both the solutions. I'm sorry I'm not sure what I am missing here, @DSM @AdamSmith

Comment: @magsheer sounds like you're doing `sorted(d())` instead of `d.items()`. Either way my code as-written is tested and working, so you've typoed something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d', 2:'e'}

# Change the name of a key
# Note this will delete the keys 1 and 2 in dict2
dict2[4] = dict2.pop(1)    # Return the corresponding value
dict2[5] = dict2.pop(2)

# Merging the two dicts (works in Python 3.5+)
result = {**dict1, **dict2}

>>> result
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep `dict2` unchanged:

```
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d', 2:'e'}

for i, k in enumerate(dict2, start=len(dict1) + 1):    
    dict1[i] = dict2[k]


>>> dict1
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: @sachindubey, added comments. Hope they're helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d',2:'e'}    
d = {}

# creating a new dictionary same as dict1 
for k,v in dict1.items():
    d[k] = v

# if dict1 needs to be updated then
# use dict1 instead of d below
for k,v in dict2.items():
    if k in d:
        d[max(d)+1] = v    # considering the max key in dict1, increment by 1
    # else:
         # any other condition
```

Output

```
# d: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d',2:'e'}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2, orient='index')

pd.concat([df1,df2]).set_axis(range(1,len(df1)+len(df2)+1), inplace=False).to_dict()[0]
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` has a `start` keyword argument, you can count from whatever number you want. Here you can use it to solve your issue  without importing any heavy external module or many loops:

```
dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
dict2 = {1:'d',2:'e'}



for index,values in enumerate(dict2.items(),start=len(dict1)+1):
    dict1[index] = values[1]

print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```